# Save a WPF Web Browser's Content to an Excel File

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I wanted to know if there is a way I can get the content of a Web Browser control and save it in a format that would open in Excel?  Currently I have an application that gets data from the user and converts it to a table and displays it in html in a WPF Web Browser control.  I can export this controls content successfully as a PDF document as follows:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".html";

File.WriteAllText(fileName, generateHtml());

//Creates a new instance of the Microsoft office interop for using MS Word
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
app.Visible = false;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(fileName);
doc.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\testExport.pdf", 17);
app.Quit();
```

This works fine for exporting a PDF file, the issue I am having is that I can't for the life of me get this to work with an excel file.  So far I am trying to do it like so:

```
  string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".html";

  File.WriteAllText(filePath, generateHtml());

  //Creates a new instance of Microsoft office interop for using MS Excel
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  //Create a new instance of a workbook
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
  //Don't Show MS Excel
  excelApp.Visible = false;
  //Open a file at location
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook2 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
  //Convert that file to an XLSX document
  excelWorkBook2.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\testExport.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
  //Close excel
  excelApp.Quit();
```

However when I try and open the file that this generates I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the filename to .xls? I believe that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet exports to xls, not xlsx

All the types can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat)

Comment: That work! Thanks, I didn't even think to try and change the extension.  Also thank you for that link it will definitely come in handy.